# Sort strings by using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

I'm a beginner in programming and my lectures now are on the topic of pointers. I'm supposed to enter strings from keyboard (up to 40) and then sort them alphabetically.

Requirements are that inputting should break as soon as "empty" string is entered, pointers to string should be stored in an array, when sorting I should move pointers to strings and I should make use of `strcmp` function.

I've stared to write my code and would like to ask you if I'm on the right track. I was advised to store strings in a two-dimensional `char` array but the problem is the program keeps asking about input even if I enter an empty line (which, I suppose, should be by just pressing `Enter`). Secondly, I'd like to ask you about the best algorithm for sorting strings considering I'm not experienced in sorting altogether.

**EDIT** I made some changes in my code and it gives the output I expected, sorts strings alphabetically. However, I'd greatly appreciate an opinion of someone more experienced in C if  there are any major flaws in my code and maybe some improvements I could make. In the part I don't understand a pointer is assigned an address, but is the way I created the pointer array really the most efficient? I'm aware I could have used `malloc` but I'd like to use a 2D array just like I did.

```
int count = 0;
char arr[40][100];
char (*poi[40])[100]; //Is the array of pointers declared right?

for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    fgets(arr[i], 101, stdin);
    count++;
    if (strcmp(arr[i], "\n") == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}

printf("\n");

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    poi[i] = &arr[i]; //I don't really understand how this part works, seems to work though 
}

for(int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(*poi[i], *poi[j]) > 0) //if I type here strcmp(arr[i], arr[j]) the output is not sorted properly, why?
        {
            char (*temp)[100] = poi[i];
            poi[i] = poi[j];
            poi[j] = temp;

        }
    }
}


//returns sorted strings    
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    printf("%s", *poi[i]);
}
```

Comment: The first step is to figure out which programming language you're required to write the code in.

Comment: @juanchopanza There is no requirement as my introductory course has both elements of `C` and `C++`. I'd appreciate a suggestion.

Comment: C++, `std::string`, `std::sort`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think `strcmp` is a requirement and I'd rather write it using that 'char' array just to test myself. Then I should probably get rid of streams. Could you help me with empty line not working?

Comment: This is a very basic error which I wouldn't expect from anybody learning using a reputable guide as a resource. Whatever method you're learning C (or C++, whatever) using, you should discard it and try something else because your current method isn't working. I'm sick of repeating myself, so I'll let you use trial and error at your risk to find the right resource. That is at least less risky than using trial and error to learn either language.

Comment: @Sebivor I know I probably mixed a few things here but pointers and differences between strings in C and C++ are the first topics I've encountered that I have difficulties to grasp. I don't mind my question getting loads of downvotes by those who think it's irrelevant - I asked for help after doing some research and not finding the answer, hoping this is the place I could find somebody to point my basic mistakes that could be improved.

Comment: @Theta When you make the mistake of comparing a pointer value such as `arr[i]` to a character constant such as `'\0'`, this shows that you've mostly failed to grasp types of all kind, not just pointers (and your compiler would be warning you). Keep the two languages separate. Also, read the output of your compiler; that's important, kind of like reading a book while you're learning (which you should also be doing, in case you missed it the first time); don't even ignore the warnings. To emphasize: If you ARE reading a book, burn it and buy a new one. It's not working.

Comment: @Theta ... and for C code, keeping to my "keep the languages separate" advice earlier, you compile using a C compiler, not a C++ compiler. I shouldn't need to tell anyone who's capable of independent research that the two languages *are* incompatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're mixing up C and C++ in a way that might not work all that well, though I'm not sure. If you're using a 2D char array then it sounds to me like you're supposed to be using lower level C paradigms. In that case I would stop using `cin` and `cout` and switch to using the `scanf` and `printf` family of functions from `<stdio.h>`. If you're supposed to use `strcmp` then that definitely sounds like the route you should be going.

As for sorting, if you're using C then take a look at the `qsort` function from `<stdlib.h>`, if you're allowed to use it.

Comment: Could you tell me how to input strings into such an array with `scanf`? I seem to have run into problems.

Comment: Greetings, @Theta. I know how to input strings into such an array using `scanf`, as does the manual (which as a C programmer, you would be expected to read, hence Michaels suggestion that you read it), and since that question has been asked before (hundreds, possibly thousands of times) and is irrelevant for this question, I don't think you'll find anybody to be your encyclopedia here. Take a more active and independent role in your education. Stop asking others to learn/explain on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::cin.getline(arr[i], 100);` instead and check the 1st char of the string `arr[i][0]` for '\0'. So your loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    std::cin.getline(arr[i], 100);
    count++;
    if (arr[i][0] == '\0') //working
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key in school is to learn, but to point you in the right direction...

```
Your loop
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
```

Your loop is requiring 40 characters.  The return character will not be picked up as a character by cin.  You must add spaces or other characters.

You are asking what is the best algorithm for sorting strings.  That really depends on so many things, but you can probably start off with a simple Bubble Sort, which is probably close to what you may be learning anyway.  Good luck.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Answer (score 0):

> ... but is the way I created the pointer array really the most efficient?

No. It's not even *correct*. In both C and C++, an *array*:

- is a *contiguous, unfragmented sequence of elements*
- has a size which is equal to the number of elements multiplied by each dimension

However, due to multiple calls to `malloc` in your code, *both* of those criteria are broken:

- there's no guarantee that `malloc` will allocate a contiguous, unfragmented sequence of elements across multiple calls
- you'll need to allocate extra bytes to represent the pointers at the second level of indirection of `poi` (`poi` is an array of 40 pointers, each pointer presumably pointing to array of 40 `char`s).

---

In C, if you want something you can *mostly* use like an array of pointers, you should use something like:

```
char (*poi)[40] = malloc(40 * sizeof *poi);
// poi[39][39] = ...
```

You could also simplify this using a `typedef`:

```
typedef char array_of_40_char[40];
array_of_40_char *poi = malloc(40 * sizeof *poi);
```

---

In C++, you'll typically be warded well away from `malloc` because there are (much) cleaner alternatives. For your usecase, you'd likely be encouraged to use something like:

```
std::vector<std::string &> *poi = new std::vector<std::string &>();
```

---

P.S. You have a buffer overflow. You shouldn't be attempting to read 100 characters into an array that can only store 40.